# How to delete a row in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code:

```
schools_users = SchoolsUsers.where(user_id: @user.id)
schools_users.each do |school_user|
    delete = true
    params[:school_id].each do |id|
        if school_user.school_id == id
            delete = false
        end
    end
    if delete
        school_user.destroy
    end
end
```

I have a join table that I query directly. I want to delete a row depending on if they are in my `params[:school_id]` or not. Now when I try to destroy that specific row I get this error.

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'schools_users.' in 'where clause':
>   DELETE FROM `schools_users` WHERE `schools_users`.`` = NULL

I am confused now. I thought the model object is a row in the table. But it seems that even those the id's are accessible, it is not really mapping to a row in the actual database. So my question is how to do it properly in rails 4? Seems very wasteful to query for the collection once, then have to call `find(id)` again to get that row specifically.

Comment: Double check that your query on SchoolsUsers return a valid result.

Comment: @John I will double check but im fairly certain it its returning the correct results since I use it elsewhere but simple only need the ids. So I know at minimum that is right. Although I realized that apparently `destroy` does not work without a primary id, which my join table does not have since its a join table.

Comment: You might need to do something like School.find(school_id).users.delete(school_user). I'm not sure if that will work, but I believe join tables in rails behave differently than a normal model.